# Custom Outlook add-in installs and works in web client, but not desktop app

Tags: outlook, office365, outlook-addin

I created a custom Outlook add-in using the Visual Studio Outlook Add-In project template. When I install the add-in from the manifest file using URLs pointing to a localhost site, everything works fine.

When I install the add-in from the manifest file using URLs pointing to an external site, it works in the Office365 Outlook web client, but not my desktop Outlook application. The add-in claims that it successfully installs, but then disappears from the list of "My Add-ins", and doesn't appear in the setting as an inactive add-in either. However, on the web client it is listed as an installed add-in and works completely fine.

Any idea on something I might be missing?

Comment: I'm also having issues getting my add in to work in desktop versions of Outlook. Everything works great in Outlook online and mobile app. Have you figured this one out?